# Op Amp Output Lower Than Expected

Tags: operational-amplifier

Im using a op amp as a voltage follower on the front end for my data acquisition card
Choose the AD817 amp powered with a 12v single power supply
I have a 4v peak to peak signal going into my system
The signal im getting on the output of the AD817 seems to be just the positive 2v peak
Don't seem to be getting the lower 2v part of the signal

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that input signal actually centered around ground? If so, there's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD817.pdf) shows, although this is a low-voltage opamp, it is *not* a rail-to-rail opamp. When powered by +12V and 0V, the output voltage can only swing between +1.5 and +10.5 volts.

Also, if/when the input signal goes below ground, obviously the output can't follow.